# Accessing PI camera from Android using Firebase

Tags: android

i am trying to send pi camera footage to firebase and access it from my android app, can this be done using realtime firebase database ?

Comment: I can't see the relevance of the Pi to this question.

Comment: You might get a (better) answer/response on SuperUser